# How to set Physical Path Credentials for an IIS site with command line?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

I've tried:

```
appcmd set config -section:sites "/[name='MySite'].userName:MyDomain\MyUser" "/[name='MySite'].password:12345"
```

But it fails.  Complains that `username` is not a valid attribute.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `appcmd` in years, but in Powershell you can do this:

```
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "userName" -value "peter"
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "password" -value "aStrongPassword"
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "logonMethod" -value "ClearText"
```

just set the three required attributes, the password will be stored encrypted, usually in the applicationhost.config file.